# hcitool lescan shows I/O error

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm trying to do a lescan using hcitool on the raspberry pi.

The command prints out

```
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error.
```

I'm not sure, what exactly happens here. My iPhone is advertising here.

I'm using a BLE dongle from IOGear.

However, if I restart my machine, it shows the a MAC address after I issue the `lescan` command, and starts showing the same error after I issue the lescan command a couple of more times. Is it like, the lescan command cannot be issued more than once?

Comment: try unplugging it and re-plugging it in.  There's all sorts of ways the dongles can get into states where they don't respond the way you want.  The IOGear one seems to be the best, though.

Comment: @aauser - did you ever solve this?  I'm stuck on the same problem.

Comment: @aauser - I should mention that I'm using a D-Link DBT-120 on 64-bit Linux Mint 16 (Petra).

Comment: Hey @DuncanBayne, not really. I did replug the usb module, however the  error kept repeating.

Comment: It appears the BlueZ BLE scanning is still pretty buggy.  However,  this thread might help: https://redbearlab.zendesk.com/entries/23561363-BLE-Shield-with-USB-Dongle-and-Python-

Comment: Also,  what is your kernel and BlueZ versions?  The end of this thread mentions kernel 3.5 or greater.  http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Anyone-able-get-BTLE-completely-4232349.S.5806578412524969986

Comment: @DavidH.Bennett: kernel 3.8, latest BlueZ built from source.  I *think* the problem may be my device ... I'm going to buy a Plugable dongle and see if that fixes it.  Of course first I have to set up a drop shipping account in the US as they don't ship to Australia.  Shave that yak.

Comment: `hcitool` has been deprecated for a long time. Do not use it.

Answer (score 63):

That happens often really often to me. I'm developing with it and it just happens from time to time. I was also able to reproduce your error within 5 minutes ;-) I'm running bluez v.5.17.
However i can run lescan more than one time without this error.

```
hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

try:

```
hciconfig hci0 down
hciconfig hci0 up
```

and check the status afterwords.

if this doesn't work or it hangs in DOWN status, try:

```
service bluetooth restart
service dbus restart
```

(all commands as superuser)

And close all application that may access bluetooth. For example hcidump.

If that doesn't work you normally have to unplug it. But there is another dirty hack to do this. It works by setting the authorized to 0 and than 1 again. This forces the usb dongle to init.

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. 


cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/

grep -i -s -r 0a5c *
…
1-1.2/idVendor:0a5c
…

cd 1-1.2

echo 0 > authorized
echo 1 > authorized
```

Comment: There is also `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset`.

Comment: In the current version bluez 5.35. I have no problems anymore.

Comment: ```hciconfig hci0 down``` then ```up``` worked for me, thanks.

Comment: ***`service dbus restart`*** *crashed* kali

Comment: @PedroLobito Do you know of any alternatives? `service dbus restart` crashes my kali VM too.

Comment: @PedroLobito service dbus restart crashed ubuntu 22 too

Answer (score 11):

For those using Bluetooth 5.x devices and getting the same error,
`sudo hcitool lescan` will throw a `Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error.` for Bluetooth 5.x LE devices, as `hcitool` is deprecated.

If you want to do a Bluetooth LE (low-energy) scan using a newer Bluetooth 5.x device, try using `bluetoothctl` instead:

```sh
bluetoothctl scan le
```

As others have mentioned, it's also worth making sure that you have the latest `bluez` version. Newer versions of `linux-firmware` or the Linux Kernel may also help if your Bluetooth device is especially new.

Answer (score 9):

Upgrading to bluez v5.43 fixed this for me.

To upgrade to the newest bluez, you need to do a "manual" installation (**not**  apt-get), downloading from [the bluez website](http://www.bluez.org/download/). I recommend [this video walkthrough](https://youtu.be/5fQR2PHMDWE?t=2056) if you are new installing packages or need help.

After installing the latest bluez, I had to run a couple commands before it worked.

1. `systemctl daemon-reload` : Restarts the system daemon.
2. `sudo service bluetooth restart` : Restarts the Bluetooth service.
3. `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` : This was needed for my Raspberry Pi 3, with the built-in BT found at `hci0`.

After these commands, `sudo hcitool lescan` and its variants all seem to work.

Comment: Thanks the video helped me a lot. I'm trying to connect to my MI Band 3. I'm able to connect it. But connection drops after a minute or so. Actually device is not found. I think it stops advertising itself after some time. But I don't know why it drops the connection.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error with `hcitool`, while `bluetoothctl` worked just fine.  Then I ran across this [article stating that all "tools using raw socket shall be considered deprecated"](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg70489.html) (hcitool, hcicfg, etc.).

So maybe just open `bluetoothctl` and issue a `scan on` command.

Comment: The question was about BLE scanning. `scan on` does not initiate a BLE scan.

Comment: @jbg scan worked fine for me with bluetoothctl on Debian 9 + Nordic BLE chipset.  Wouldn't have posted if it didn't.

Answer (score 4):

**`sudo service bluetooth restart` helps me on Raspibian Buster.**

in case of `Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error.` error in `sudo hcitool lescan`.

*But is is occuring randomly again, so some system library has probably some issue.*

Comment: After some fighting with this issue I disabled the internal Raspberry bluetooth and bought USB Bluetooth dongle with BLE support. (model: CONNECT IT BT403).
The USB bluetooth works perfectly for a weeks without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

To those finding this question now, it is fixed as of Bluez v5.41. All you need to to is download and install. You can download the lastest version from http://www.bluez.org/download/.

Answer (score 2):

I have removed Bluez and then I just installed it again, and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt remove --purge bluez bluez-* -y


apt install bluez
```

And then

```
hcitool lescan
```

That should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that HCI is currently in use. In my case I must stop Node-Red and it works. So take care, that the HCI isn't in use.

Restart the HCI is a way, to solve the problem temporarily, but it doesn't solve the problem right.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Version 5.53
I have two Bluetooth devices (hic0 and hic1)
I tried all kinds of ways to to reset the devices ...
The only way that worked was to physically unplug and re-insert the hic1 dongle.
This is the one that supports ble. Then it works until I reboot.
I really wish there was a pure software solution way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me though is opening up the Bluetooth settings on my Ubuntu and manually removing the unused devices. Immediately lescan started working.

Answer (score -10):

```
sudo hcitool lescan
```

Just use sudo & will scan

Comment: Thats work for me with TinkerForge and BlueZ 5.44 :) Thank you

Comment: When sudo is missing, the error is "Operation not permitted", not Input/Output error