# gatttool and hcitool on Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to a device using `gatttool` on Linux. I run `hcitool lescan` to get the device MAC address, and then `gatttool -i hci1 -b <macaddr> -t random -I`. Then I type `connect`. I see [CON] as expected, but the problem is that it disappears automatically after about 1s, with no error messages. I have been searching for hours, but I don't see why that is so?

Note: I have run `hcitool lecc` before running `gatttool` one time just to try it, but it seems to me that since then, `gatttool` connection is not working properly anymore (unexpected disconnection as explained above). Is it because I have used `hcitool lecc`? If yes, is there a way to "undo" it?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps you because I'm seeing this behavior on my Raspberry Pi (an up-to-date wheezy version) and bluez 5.18 (released April 2014.)

1. I can **connect** to my BLE peripheral from the command line after doing an **lecc** without any problems. I don't think you need to reset after an **lecc**. Regardless, if you do want to reset your BT dongle because it is in some funky state, look at [this excellent step-by-step guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062037/hcitool-lescan-shows-i-o-error/23059924#23059924) to reset the BT dongle. I have followed these steps with consistent results.
2. I can **connect** and query say **primary** but more often than not, the connection drops before I can manually type in **primary**. See the results below. If I use the up/down arrows after connecting to quickly scroll to **primary**, I am able to see primary services offered by this peripheral without any problems.

> **~ $ sudo gatttool -I -i hci0 -m 48 -b 20:CD:39:A8:11:AF**
>
> **[20:CD:39:A8:11:AF][LE]> connect**
>
> Attempting to connect to 20:CD:39:A8:11:AF
>
> Connection successful
>
> **[20:CD:39:A8:11:AF][LE]> primary**
>
> Command Failed: Disconnected

Comment: Finally I changed my board because I aboslutely didn't see where the porblem came from... The same set of commands runs perfectly on my new board, so I guess it was more of a hardware bug with the faulty board which made it disconnect for no reason after some seconds..